# Antichains and weighted sums

Tags: combinatorics

Given an antichain $S_1,S_2,\dots,S_m$ of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\},$ does there always exist positive integers $x, y_1,\dots,y_n$ so that for $i=1,\dots,m$ we have:

$$\sum_{k\in S_i} y_k =x\tag 1$$

(Antichain means that for for $i\neq j,$ we have $S_i\not\subseteq S_j.$)

Just a question that occurred to me while working on another problem.

Certainly, given $x,y_1,\dots,y_n,$ the set
$$\mathcal A =\left\{S\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}\mid \sum_{k\in S} y_k =x\right\}$$ is an antichain, so this question asks if all antichains are a subset of an antichain of the form $\mathcal A.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

**Counterexample**

Let $n=5$ and $$\mathcal A=\{45,123,124,125,134,135,234,245\}
$$

By the symmetry of $\mathcal A,$ we can see that if there is a solution $x,y_1,\dots,y_5,$ there is a solution with $y_1=y_2=y_3$ and $y_4=y_5.$

But then $x=3y_1=2y_1+y_4=2y_4.$ The second equality means $y_1=y_4$ while the third equality means that $2y_1=y_4.$ This means $y_1=y_4=0,$ violating the requirement that the $y_i$ are positive.